# how to modify code to get iframe to load onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, onclick

I am trying to speed up the loading of a page that has a few iframes. These iframes contain videos that when a text is clicked slide down and start playing. My original code works.

html

```
<span id="clickableText" class="link">click me</span>.<span><iframe id="frame" class="rect" src="iframe.html" scrolling="no" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0></iframe></span>
```

the css has a class of "rect" that is basically a collapsed div and a class of "open" that slides up with a transition.

css

```
.rect{
    float: left;
    height: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.open {
    height: 11.4vw;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

the jQuery deals with adding and removing the class "open" and playing and pausing the video.

jQuery

```
var frame = $("#frame");
var player;

frame.bind("load", function () {
    player = $(this).contents().find("#myVid");
    player.on('ended', function () {
        frame.removeClass("open");    
    });
 });

 $("#clickableText").click(function(){
    if (frame.hasClass("open")) {
        frame.removeClass("open");
        player[0].pause();
  } else {
        frame.addClass("open");
        player[0].play();
  }
 });
```

So anyway, this works. But because I have a few videos on my page, it loads quite slowly. So, looking online, I found some suggestions along the lines of loading the iframes on click. So I am trying to modify my code by adding this line:

```
   frame.attr("src","iframe.html");
```

in here:

```
 $("#clickableText").click(function(){

frame.attr("src","iframe.html");

if (frame.hasClass("open")) {

etc...
```

and also of course, deleting the iframe source from the html, so getting rid of this bit from my iframe tag:

```
src="iframe.html"
```

Which fixes the page loading slowly but... here is where I am stuck. When the iframe opens up, you can see the first image of the video but it's not playing and there is no sound. The loading of the page is brilliant though, so if I can get it to work, I am on the right track... needless to say, any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the iframe src in html:

```
<iframe id="frame" class="rect" scrolling="no" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0></iframe>
```

Call source file on click in javascript:

```
onClick='document.getElementById("frame").src="iframe.html";'
```

OR call source file on click via jquery:

```
$("#frame").attr("src", "iframe.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the iframe src in the data attribute and load it on click of the clickable text like so:

```
    $('#clickableText').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('iframe').each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('open');
          $(this).attr('src', ' ');
        });         
        var vURL = $(this).find('iframe').data('src');
        $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', vURL).addClass('open');
 });
```

The code above also loops through and removes open from currently playing iframes if you have multiple on the same page. This technique is good for pages with multiple iframes as none of them will load unless they are clicked. As for the storage of the src set up your iframe code like so:

```
<iframe id="frame" class="rect" data-src="iframe.html" src="" scrolling="no" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0></iframe>
```